# I am unable to install the firebase cocoa pod on my Mac

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to install the above pods but I am getting an error during the installation of firebase.
I cannot understand the error that it is giving.
error:

I don't understand what is above error is referring to and why it says anaconda3 I am not using anaconda anywhere for this code.

as suggested in some answers provided to similar problems I tried
pod repo remove master
and then:
pod setup
but it did not resolve the problem .

## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Flash Chat' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

# Pods for Flash Chat
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'ChameleonFramework'
end

(base) Sarthaks-Air:Flash_Chat sarthakdandriyal$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing ChameleonFramework (2.1.0)
Installing Firebase (6.3.0)

[!] Error installing Firebase
[!] /Users/sarthakdandriyal/anaconda3/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/1f/3fld6d6d3dxfdx2mf363_wxm0000gn/T/d20190620-6634-xjii3m/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/f64cf2cc2acbf58d/Firebase-6.3.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sarthakdandriyal/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found

I am using Xcode 9.4 could that be reason for this error?

Comment: Maybe a transient network error. Try again,

Comment: no I don't think its a network error.i installed multiple things for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running conda install libssh2 solved the problem for me.